# Syncing app for cloud based doc files

Tags: web-apps, automation, document-converter, synchronization, microsoft-onenote

I have hundreds of pages of notes/notebooks in Evernote and Onenote and recently I've needed to collaborate with others on Google Docs. I need a good syncing app that syncs all of my documents together. In this case, syncing means not just copying files, but actually converting them. Evernote, Google Docs and Onenote use different formats for word processing. The app should be web-based because cnce the files are synced, it doesn't matter which operating system I access the files on (windows, Android, ios, etc.)

I've used zapier and IFTTT but, unfortunately, they only trigger a sync to create new notes written on Evernote into Google Docs and Onenote. They don't seem to copy/backup older notes nor can they sync new notes written on Docs or Onenote.

There is an app I experimented with called CloudHQ which actually does everything! But it's expensive. I'd like to use a free app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS? Only Evernote/OneNote/Google docs?

Comment: If you're asking for an Android app, be welcome to take a look at my app list for [Synchronizing Files and Folders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync). Especially watch out for *FolderSync* (and find it recommended [in these answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=foldersync+is%3Aanswer)).

Comment: I'm interested in Android and Windows apps for syncing. Once the docs are synced,  I'll be able to access the files on both OSs. @Izzy I'll check out that link. It looks promising!

Comment: In order to clarify : I'm using Android and Windows but I would like the app to be Web based. I'd like the syncing to be done between Evernote, Onenote and Google Docs online between the apps--not between my phone's folders and an online storage. Once the docs are synced,  I'll be able to access the files on both OSs (or any computer).

Comment: The last 2 comments you should [edit] into your question, as they contain essential details (not everyone reads through all the comments). Also consider dropping some tag (e.g. `document-converter` and `google-apps` don't seem to fit at all), and instead add the `web-apps` tag.

Comment: Thanks... Made the edits. Except I kept the document converter tag because I actually do need the conversion. (see edit). I wish there was a Google docs tag because that is also needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, good news today that Onenote has a new feature that allows migration from Evernote to Onenote, so automatic syncing will soon be possible at least from those two web/android/windows apps:

http://www.computerworld.com/article/3043541/enterprise-applications/first-look-onenote-offers-evernote-users-a-migration-tool.html#comments

Now hopefully there will be a syncing app to connect them together with Google docs for automatic backup and syncing.